# A more efficient way to do a select insert that involves over 300 columns?

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to find a more efficient way to write PL/SQL Query to
to select insert from a table with 300+ columns, to the back up version of that table (same column names + 2 extra columns).

I could simply type out all the column names in the script (example below), but with that many names, it will bother me... :(

```
INSERT INTO 
   TABLE_TEMP 
   (column1, column2, column3, etc)
(SELECT column1, column2, column3, etc FROM TABLE WHERE id = USER_ID);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As Jarlh said, you can use `INSERT INTO TABLE_TEMP SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE id = USER_ID`, but only if your columns of the TABLE_TEMP are in the same order that the TABLE structure @andre3wap

Comment: @jarlh - This is a great approach. Only issue I am facing is that; since `TABLE_TEMP` has 2 extra columns that are not on `TABLE`, How can I  exclude these 2 columns with your approach. I did remove them from the query but I get `invalid identifier and not enough values` errors

Comment: Specify literals/null for those two extra columns.

Comment: @jarlh - thanks alot, you should post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: that can't be normalized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify literals/null for those two extra columns.

```
INSERT INTO 
   TABLE_TEMP 
SELECT t1.*, null, null FROM TABLE t1 WHERE id = USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily build a column list for any given table:

```
select table_catalog
    ,table_schema
    ,table_name
    ,string_agg(column_name, ', ' order by ordinal_position)
from information_schema.columns
where table_catalog = 'catalog_name'
    and table_schema = 'schema_name'
    and table_name = 'table_name'
group by table_catalog
    ,table_schema
    ,table_name
```

That should get you nearly where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

The question tag says plsql, which is Oracle or one of its variants. Here is an example of doing it in Oracle:

```
drop table brianl.deleteme1;
drop table brianl.deleteme2;

CREATE TABLE brianl.deleteme1
(
   a     INTEGER
 , b     INTEGER
 , c     INTEGER
 , efg   INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE brianl.deleteme2
(
   b     INTEGER
 , c     INTEGER
 , d     INTEGER
 , efg   INTEGER
);

DECLARE
   l_ownerfrom   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'BRIANL';
   l_tablefrom   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'DELETEME1';
   l_ownerto     VARCHAR2 (30) := 'BRIANL';
   l_tableto     VARCHAR2 (30) := 'DELETEME2';
   l_comma       VARCHAR2 (1) := NULL;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('insert into ' || l_ownerto || '.' || l_tableto || '(');

   FOR eachrec IN (  SELECT f.column_name
                       FROM all_tab_cols f INNER JOIN all_tab_cols t ON (f.column_name = t.column_name)
                      WHERE f.owner = l_ownerfrom
                        AND f.table_name = l_tablefrom
                        AND t.owner = l_ownerto
                        AND t.table_name = l_tableto
                   ORDER BY f.column_name)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_comma || eachrec.column_name);
      l_comma   := ',';
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (') select ');
   l_comma   := NULL;

   FOR eachrec IN (  SELECT f.column_name
                       FROM all_tab_cols f INNER JOIN all_tab_cols t ON (f.column_name = t.column_name)
                      WHERE f.owner = l_ownerfrom
                        AND f.table_name = l_tablefrom
                        AND t.owner = l_ownerto
                        AND t.table_name = l_tableto
                   ORDER BY f.column_name)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_comma || eachrec.column_name);
      l_comma   := ',';
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' from ' || l_ownerfrom || '.' || l_tablefrom || ';');
END;
```

This results in this output:

```
insert into BRIANL.DELETEME2(
B
,C
,EFG
) select
B
,C
,EFG
from BRIANL.DELETEME1;
```

Nicely formatted:

```
INSERT INTO brianl.deleteme2 (b, c, efg)
   SELECT b, c, efg
     FROM brianl.deleteme1;
```